# How to create a child route that takes an exact word

Tags: angular, typescript, routes

Here is the code:

```js
{path : 'recipes', component:RecipesComponent, children:[
    {path:':id', component:RecipeDetailComponent},
    {path:':new', component:NewRecipeComponent }
  ]},
```

Whatever link as :

http://localhost:4200/recipes/new, or

http://localhost:4200/recipes/12, or

http://localhost:4200/recipes/details

They all open the RecipeDetailComponent component.

How do i set {path:':new', component:NewRecipeComponent } so that http://localhost:4200/recipes/**new** opens NewRecipeComponent component?

Comment: Could you add more context? Because right now, `:id` and `:new` are in conflict.

Comment: I made the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you write: `:new` or `:id`, angular will interpet them as variable.
If you desire a FIXED path, you need to remove the `:`.

```
{path : 'recipes', component:RecipesComponent, children:[
    {path:'new', component: NewRecipeComponent }
    {path:':id', component: RecipeDetailComponent},
  ]},
```

Don't forget that in `RecipesComponent`, you need also to display the children.

It's done with:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Then http://localhost:4200/recipes/new opens `NewRecipeComponent` component inside the component `RecipesComponent`

Comment: It worked thank you!

Do fixed paths must be on top of non fixed paths in the hierarchy?